# How get DirectoryServicesCOMException from InnerException?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, active-directory, try-catch

How I can get DirectoryServicesCOMException ExtendedErrorMessage from InnerException? 
Programm catch only "catch (Exception e)", so this dont work:

```
try
{
   ...
}
   catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
{
   throw e;
}
```

[screen](http://s18.postimg.org/728inv9ll/zzz.png)

Something like :

```
try
{
   ...
}
   catch (Exception e)
{
   throw e.InnerException.DirectoryServicesCOMException ....;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
if (e.InnerException is DirectoryServicesCOMException)
{
    DirectoryServicesCOMException innerException = (DirectoryServicesCOMException)e.InnerException;
    // do whatever is correct with these kind of exception
}
```

Comment: Great, thankyou very much!!!! (Sorry,cant "+" your answer, reputation lower then 15...)